# VB Excel adding a Table to a Word Document

Tags: excel

Am not that VB conversant. I specialise in algorithms and occasionally need to resort to it.  Here is the situation.

Running an Excel Macro, have successfully opened and edited an existing Word Document by creating a 2-Column Table (PS:  got the code over the forum).

However, the document (a Template of two) gets overwritten by the 2 column Table I am creating.  Tried to look for code that would allow me to position the table after the 2 pages.

[Code I used](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qQRHD.jpg)

Comment: Please add the code as text and not as a linked image. Images cannot be parsed by the search engine and may be lost.

Comment: ... and most of all, we cannot copy&paste it to try and execute it. And if you use VBA you should add that tag.

Comment: Apologies for the inconvenience...  first time I have been on a forum...
(Although my common sense should have made me realise that)
Thanks for the suggestions...
I will repost with the tag...
A question...  do I add the codes as an attached file? Or simply copy the code into this panel?